# Bq aquaris m10 ,install Japanese input programs

Tags: input, japanese, mozc

Ihave BQaquaris M10 ubuntu edition.
I want to input Japanese from an external keyboard.
Can I install Japanese input programs such as ibus-anthy, mozc or fcitx-mozc, anthy?
Other methods can be used.